# How to wait untill drop down values load in if else condition in robot framework

Tags: selenium, robotframework

My scenarios are: I have two drop down values side by side if the first drop down-selected based on the value selected second drop-down values will be loaded from that we need to pick one value. in one case from the first drop down if I select unknown or any legal purpose I should not go for the second dropdown. this is what the requirement I have please help me out. Below is the code I have written

Variables

```
${var1}=    Unknown
${var2}=    Any legal purpose
```

The user selects random NAICS code and subcode from the drop-down

```
${selectedNAICScode}= User selects NAICS code from the drop down       
${NAICS_code}  run keyword if    
${selectedNAICScode}!=${var1} or ${selectedNAICScode}!=${var2} run keywords
        ...    element should be visible        xpath://select[@id="ddlNAICSSubCode"]

#     ...    is visible          ${NAICS_subcode}
...    User selects NAICS-sub code from the drop down
...    ELSE     run keywords
...    element should not be visible        xpath://select[@id='ddlNAICSSubCode']
```

Even though we are giving one argument when I run the script it is saying expecting 1 to 2 arguments but got 0. my question is how we can wait until the drop-down values load into the drop-down in else condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following functionality:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, INSERT_INTEGER_WAITING_TIME);

boolean waitUntil = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("ENTER_YOUR_XPATH_OR_OTHER_ATTRIBUTE")));
```

In this way, your action will happen only when the element is going to be visible.

If you need further information check this [link](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/until.html)