# selenium chrome Timed out receiving message from renderer: 300.000

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have been trying to upload a gallery of pics to the website but for a large number of files(>150 max 350 files) how can I increase the time for selenium according to my wish.

Edit:
code added

it is showing this error

```
    File "C:\Users\ronni\OneDrive\Desktop\try1.py", line 39, in <module>
    name2.submit()
  File "C:\Users\ronni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 89, in submit
    "if (arguments[0].dispatchEvent(e)) { arguments[0].submit() }", form)
  File "C:\Users\ronni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 636, in execute_script
    'args': converted_args})['value']
  File "C:\Users\ronni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\ronni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 300.000
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.129)
```

**CODE**: I have omiited the zero folder but it looks like this

```
zero=['C:\\Users\\ronni\\OneDrive\\Documents\\New folder\\7.1\\1', with same paths like this]
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
import glob
import os
import shutil
import re
import n2w
driver=webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/ronni/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
lists=[[]]*len(zero)
for i in range(0,len(zero)):
    arr=glob.glob((zero[i])+"\*")
    lists[i]=sorted(arr)
    lists[i].sort(key=len)
url='http://minin.herokuapp.com/login'
driver.get(url)
sleep(2)
user_name=driver.find_element_by_name("username")
user_name.send_keys("admin")
passwd=driver.find_element_by_name("password")
passwd.send_keys("password")
passwd.submit()
sleep(3)
url1="http://minin.herokuapp.com/c/n"
driver.get(url1)
sleep(2)
v=471
for i in range(0,len(lists)):
    c=n2w.convert(v)
    name=driver.find_element_by_name("ca[name]")
    name.send_keys(c)
    name1=driver.find_element_by_name("ca[price]")
    name1.send_keys(v)
    image=driver.find_element_by_name("images")
    for j in range(0,(len(lists[i])-1)):
        image.send_keys(lists[i][j])
    name2=driver.find_element_by_name("ca[description]")
    name2.send_keys("admin")
    name2.submit()
    v=v+1
    sleep(2)
    url1="http://minin.herokuapp.com/c/n"
    driver.get(url1)
    sleep(2)
```

Comment: Please upload your source code too.

Comment: @dpapadopoulos code added i tried driver.set_page_load_timeout(30000) but it logs me out when upload is complete

Comment: Firstly, the sleep() method is not a good practice. You should wait for the element to be visible dynamically and not by using static waiting time. Check here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61569419/how-to-wait-untill-drop-down-values-load-in-if-else-condition-in-robot-framework/61570812#61570812

Comment: Your code seems to be okay, so I guess there is something wrong with the chromedriver. Check this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48450594/selenium-timed-out-receiving-message-from-renderer